# Vue js dynamically added property not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component which displays has a prop called `obj`. `obj` has two properties: `obj.title` and `obj.body`. Each is bound to a textfield so as to be reactive and editable.

```
<div id="app">
  <controller :obj="{title: 'TITLE'}"></controller>
</div>

<template id="controller">

  <input type="text" v-model="obj.title">
  <p>{{ obj.title }}</p>
  <input type="text" v-model="obj.body">
  <p>{{ obj.body }}</p>

</template>
```

The `title` property is part of the prop which is bound to the component. But the `body` property has been added dynamically during the created callback. Here is the js:

```
Vue.component('controller', {
  template: '#controller',
  props: ['obj'],

  created: function() {
    this.obj.body = "BODY";
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

The problem is that the `body` property isn't behaving reactively. Changes to the `body` textfield are not reflected by `{{ obj.body }}`.

The vue website has a section about [Adding and Deleting Properties](http://012.vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html#Adding_and_Deleting_Properties), but I couldn't get their suggestions to work.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/nr23jdya/) demonstrating the problem.

Note: it has been suggested that I declare the `body` property at the same time as the `title` property. This would work, but for my use-case the property needs to be added dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have selected this as the Accepted solution because it is what I would recommend to someone else with the same problem.

As user [crabbly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6047599/crabbly) noticed, the reactivity can only be re-established if the prop's reference is updated.

I think the nicest way to do this is by making a shallow copy:

```
created: function() {
   this.obj.body = 'BODY'
   /**
    * ... other code that adds other properties and messes around with obj...
    */
   this.obj = Object.assign({}, this.obj);
}
```

... here, `Object.assign` is responsible for updating the reference.

This solution is currently not supported by IE, though any "clone" function will do (e.g. `this.obj = jQuery.extend({}, this.obj);` also works).

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the `body` property when passing the prop:

```
<controller :obj="{title: 'TITLE', body: null}"></controller>
```

Or in your `created` method:

```
created: function() {
    this.obj = {
        title: this.obj.title,
        body: 'some body
    }
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/33721g9w/

Comment: That would work, but for my use case I won't know if the property will be called `body`, or even if any extra properties will be added until the component has been been created. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Interesting, I can't see why a component would create different properties like that, but I updated the answer with a solution that should work for you. Check it out.

Comment: I accepted my own solution because it explains *why* reactivity was broken, and provides a solution for the most general case. Thank you for your help, you pointed me in the right direction.